# Android Spinner default style

Tags: android

In my app I can't see the spinner style like [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/spinner.html) . I always get a spinner without a divider and with an arrow pointing down.

I downloaded others apps and the spinner looks like I want. My Android version is 4.1.2 and the app theme is Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar

What theme/style should I use to see the spinner like the link?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should user android:Theme.Holo or some of its descendants.

On Your res/values/styles.xml put:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo">
```

and in your manifest, make Activity use this style, like this:

```
<activity
   android:name=".MainActivity"
   android:theme="@style/AppTheme"/>
```

Now it should look like what you want.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. When I try to use Theme.Holo I get an exception from appCompat. But I could use the Holo Spinner style like this   @android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.Spinner and now I see the spinner like I want.

Comment: You're welcome :) If your Activity extends AcitivtyCompact you'll get that exception, but your fix is enough.